# jQuery how to use .nextAll() in a html table

Tags: html, jquery

I am to create function where when input 100 in row3, row4 and row5 the rows below it will also get 100 inserted into them. I am using nextAll() to try to do this but I think it doesn't work because the rows are not together in an order. Is there some thing I am not doing right?

```js
 $("input[id^=row]").on("change", function() {
        $(this).nextAll("input[id^=row]").val($(this).val());
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Annual Premium<br>(Beginning of Year)</th>
        <th>Benefits<br>(End of Year)</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Policyholder's Cashflow</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td id='annual0'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit0'><input class='row' id='row0'></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td id='annual1'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit1'><input class='row' id='row1'></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td id='annual2'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit2'><input class='row' id='row2'></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td id='annual3'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit3'><input class='row' id='row3'></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td id='annual4'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit4'><input class='row' id='row4'></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 $("input[id^=row]").on("input", function() {
        $(this).nextAll("input[id^=row]").val($(this).val());
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
```

```html
 <tr>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Annual Premium<br>(Beginning of Year)</th>
        <th>Benefits<br>(End of Year)</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Policyholder's Cashflow</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td id='annual0'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit0'><input class='row' id='row'></td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td id='annual1'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit1'><input class='row' id='row1'></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td id='annual2'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit2'><input class='row' id='row2'></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td id='annual3'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit3'><input class='row' id='row3'></td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td id='annual4'>0</td>
        <td id='benefit4'><input class='row' id='row4'></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try `on("input")` instead of `on('change')`,